# Is an undergraduate thesis a requirement to get into grad school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, undergraduate

I'm about to start my last term as engineering student, and my goal after I graduate is to get into grad school and pursue a master's degree in Computer Science or software development. However, my university is offering me two choices in order to opt for my degree: undergraduate thesis, or just internships (+ internship project). I already received some suggestions from colleagues that due quarantine and confinement is preferable to just go for internships, which I'm almost finishing working from home.

Nonetheless, I'd like to keep asking for second opinions about this. Can I freely choose only my internships without worrying if that could harm my application into grad school? I'd deeply appreciate any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since not all colleges or universities offer an undergraduate thesis option, the answer is No.

Comment: What country are you asking about?

Comment: The (presumably not research related) internship would probably not harm your application to grad school, but if you are looking for a research based masters then research experience (by doing the thesis) may help.

Comment: @Buffy hello Buffy, to be more precise Canada and Spain. Probably I'll be considering UK and other universities from Europe too, but so far those are the ones I've been taking into account.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I see. So, let's say the thesis would be a plus in my application? Or is it an important requirement still? Thanks for the kind suggestion.

Comment: @JonCuster hello Jon, thanks for your comment. I think it's clear now, but what if the program is research based? That would be an impediment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, it's not necessary.**

Of course, all other things being equal, writing a (good) undergraduate thesis can only help. It demonstrates research capability and independence, and you'll probably get a more detailed letter of recommendation than you would from a professor who you saw only in class. But a similar argument can be made for many extracurricular activities, and you don't have time to do *everything.*

If you choose to write a thesis, do so because you are interested in the challenge and the topic, not because you are afraid not writing one will prevent you from getting into graduate school.

Comment: Thank you Max for the kind response. I'll take your comment into account. Best regards.